# What is the default return value of a Boolean function in C++?

Tags: c++, boolean

What could be the return value of a boolean function in C++ if I do not return something? And what could be the return value if I just return a true value and not the false one?  Here is my code:

```
bool f(int a)
{
//    return value?
}

bool f(int a)
{
    if(a%2) return true;
//    return value here?
}
```

Comment: You can't not return something from a function that is supposed to return something. That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return : *Flowing off the end of a value-returning function (except main) without a return statement is undefined behavior.*

Comment: Please don't use images of code; just include it as properly formatted text in your question.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you mean to ask about the default return **value**, not the default return **type**.  (The return type is exactly what you defined it to be, in this case `bool`. It's not a default, it's explicit.) I'll edit your question. Please verify that my edit reflects what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

The return type is the one you define in the function prototype. Note that there is no default return value for functions in C++ (except for special function `main`). A function that is supposed to return a value must return a value in all its code paths. Otherwise you yield undefined behaviour.
Cf, for example, this online [C++ working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> **9.6.3 The return statement**
>
> ...
>
> Flowing off the end of a constructor, a destructor, or a function with
>   a cv void return type is equivalent to a return with no operand.
>   Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function other than main (6.8.3.1)
>   results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I've edited the question. I'm 99% sure the OP meant to ask about the return *value*, not the return *type*.

Comment: Good point about `main`. Nicked that. Have an upvote for good feelings!

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour on calling a non-`void` function (other than `main`) where program control reaches a branch that does not have an explicit `return` value is *undefined*.

(Note that this is a stronger condition than in C where the behaviour is undefined only if you attempt to use the function return value.)

In C++, you can use `auto` to get the compiler to work out the return type for you:

```
auto foo(int n)
{
    if (n >= 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but the type of `foo` is still *static* in the sense that it is known at compile time. This approach is particularly useful when working with templates. It is not designed to allow you to be sloppy with your types.